# counterclock angle between two vectors in cpp

Tags: math

I'm trying to get the counterlockwise angle in degree between vector A and vector B starting from vector A. The Vectors are in 2D space. To specify, Vec A is not in the center of the coordinate system, for an easy example let Vec A be 4,4 and Vec B be 1,1. This should result in an angle of 235°.

[image]

Can't seem to find the right formula to solve this problem.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question

Comment: Should I ask the question in maths exchange then?